# Excel Equivalent of a for loop

Tags: excel

I have a link budget set up in an excel worksheet.  The worksheet has one main input cell that the user can change to see how the data rate is affected.  I want to make a plot that shows how the result cell (data rate) changes as the value in the input cell goes up.  If I were working in python I would create a list of input values using `range`, loop over each value with a for loop to calculate the result, and append the resulting value to a new list. Then I would plot the results.

I haven't used excel for much in the past so I'm not sure how I would do this in my worksheet.  Is there an Excel equivalent of the for loop sequence I mentioned above?

Comment: Well, there is a loop in vba. I guess you would have to show an example with a little more detail of what you need, so people can see, if it can be done without vba. You might also want to look into the scenario function of ecxel (data sheet).

Comment: There is a tool called "data table" you could try. It takes an array of input values, a reference to the input cell in the sheet, and a reference to the output cell. Then it runs the sheet several times and puts an array of output values next to your input array. There is a two-varable version too. Slow to run but requires no re-programming!

Comment: @MLind I will give the data table function a shot. Thanks!

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to loop - does [this site](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html) help (`for loop`, `do while`, and `do until` loops).